# Does there exist numerically balanced dice with odd numbers of faces?

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, recreational-mathematics

This question is motivated by "[Numerically Balanced Dice](https://doi.org/10.1515/9781400889136-016)" by Bosch, Fathauer, and Segerman, in which they produced the most numerically balanced d20 and d120. After reading this paper, I start to wonder whether there exists numerically balanced dice of odd numbers of faces. I tried balancing dice made in the following fashion ([Fair Dice](https://doi.org/10.1080/00029890.1989.11972191) by Diaconis and Keller):

> As an example, let us consider an infinite prism with a regular n-gon as its cross
> section. Let us cut it with two planes a distance L apart perpendicular to its
> generators, to produce a polyhedron with n + 2 faces. For L large this solid has
> very low probability of landing on either of its two ends, whereas, for very small L it
> has a high probability of landing on one of them. Therefore by continuity there is
> some value of L for which it has the same probability of landing on any one of its
> n + 2 faces. When n is odd this yields a fair die with an odd number of faces

I have convinced myself that dice of this kind cannot be "exactly" balanced (neither the cost of face sums nor the cost of vertex sums, as defined by Bosch, can be exactly zero). I fiddled with these dice for a bit and saw that there exists arrangements that make the face cost in the order of $n^2$ and vertex cost in the order of $n$ and vice versa. This is probably not the best we can do. However, these details are not important compared with my ultimate curiosity though:

Do there exist numerically balanced (or almost numerically balanced) dice with odd numbers of faces?

Comment: To make questions searchable, you should type the relevant text rather than posting an image.  What does "almost numerically balanced" mean precisely?

Comment: What is numerically balanced dice?

Comment: What do you mean by face/vertex cost?

Comment: I am not sure what the proper name is for them, but there are dice where an elongated regular prism is capped with a pyramid on each end, which prevents them from standing on the ends. These look quite ugly but are well balanced, even for an odd number of sides.

Comment: Since you're not sharing the definitions, Ye, I can't tell whether polyhedra need to have any symmetries in order to be "numerically balanced". I'll just point out that there are no semi-regular polyhedra with an odd number of faces, other than the prisms. https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Semi-regular_polyhedra